# UITabController iphone development

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am following the Iphone UI tab controller tutorial, I basically mimicked the code at the bottom
[link text](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingToolbarControllers/UsingToolbarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW1)

```
// Create a temporary window object to assign to the window property 
    UIWindow *tempWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]
 bounds]];
    // Make the window background red so that you can see that the window has been added
    tempWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.window = tempWindow;
    [tempWindow release];


    // add the tab bar controller
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];


    PhoneContactsView *phoneContactsView = [[[PhoneContactsView alloc] init] autorelease];
    OtherContactsView *otherContactsView = [[[OtherContactsView alloc] init] autorelease];

    //Add all the view to the tabBarView
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:otherContactsView,phoneContactsView, nil];

    //Add all the button's to the bar

    UITabBarItem *otherContactsTabBarItem = 
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemTopRated tag:1];       
    otherContactsBarItem.title = @"My Contacts";
    otherContactsView.tabBarItem = otherContactsBarItem;    
    [otherContactsBarItem release];

    UITabBarItem *phoneContactsBarItem =
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:1];       
    phoneContactsView.tabBarItem = phoneContactsBarItem;    
    [phoneContactsBarItem release];

    tabBarController.selectedViewController
    = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [tabBarController release];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

OtherContacts and PhoneContacts are just default empty view, I only changed there background to make sure they were loading.
When I run this, The first view loads, but I am unable to click on the Tab Bar to change between the view's am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the BUG:

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[tabBarController release]; <------------- I am releasing the tabBarController while still in use 
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Thats why the tab bar controller was unresponsive.
-daniel

Answer (score 0):

If OtherContacts and PhoneContacts are "UIView" classes and not UIViewController classes, that would explain the problems - the tab bar controller needs UIViewController references.

Comment: They are both UIViewControllers, they both have a title set also.